# Adding a numerical value to a DOM created element

Tags: javascript, dom, random, addition, dice

I have a university assignment where I am supposed to code a dice roller. All of the HTML structure for the dice roller is supposed to be created by the DOM, except for the button to start the actual roller.

You can add and subtract dice from the roller. When you press the button to add a dice a d6 is created with a random number of dots ( 1 through 6). You can add up to 40 dice to the roller.

The code for adding a random die looks like this: (If this is the wrong method please tell me :) )

```
var addLi = document.createElement("li"); // this creates the button to add a die.
addLi.className = "add";
addLi.addEventListener("click", addRandomDice) // this fires of the function to create a random die.

toolbarUl.appendChild(addLi); 

function get_random()
{
    var ranNum= Math.floor(Math.random()*6);
    return ranNum;
}

function addRandomDice(){
var whichDice=get_random();

    var dice=new Array(5)
    dice[0]=diceSideOne;
    dice[1]=diceSideTwo;
    dice[2]=diceSideThree;   
    dice[3]=diceSideFour;
    dice[4]=diceSideFive;
    dice[5]=diceSideSix;

    contentUl.appendChild(dice[whichDice].cloneNode(true)); // creates a random d6 dice.

};
```

The code for a die with one dot like this:

```
// dice-side-one li
var diceSideOne = document.createElement("li");
diceSideOne.className = "dice dice-side-one";
```

The code for a die with 2 dots looks like this:

```
// dice-side-two li
var diceSideTwo = document.createElement("li");
diceSideTwo.className = "dice dice-side-two";
```

And et cetera...

The value of all the dice is supposed to be added together and shown to the user.

My question is: How can I add a numerical value to each dice which represents it's amount of dots. So that I can add them all together to show the user the summ of all the dice.

In other words. If I have 5 d6 dice, with the faces 2, 3, 5, 4, 5. How can I show the user the sum of the dice faces rolled, which in this case would be 19 to the user.

Comment: Use HTML data-* Attributes see documentation on http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp

Comment: Hey thanks for replying! Would it look something like this:

" diceSideOne.dataset.indexNumber // "1" "

Sorry if I'm way off.I'm abit of a noob =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify an attribute on each die that holds its value.  When creating the dice variables try something like this:

```
// dice-side-one li
var diceSideOne = document.createElement("li");
diceSideOne.className = "dice dice-side-one";
diceSideOne.setAttribute('data-diceValue', '1');
```

Then when you want to sum up the values of the dice you added you can access that attribute in a loop over all elements with a class of `dice`.

```
function getSumDiceValue() {
  var dice = document.getElementsByClassName('dice');
  var diceTotal = 0;
  for(var i = 0; i < dice.length; i++){
    diceTotal += Number(dice[i].getAttribute('data-diceValue'));
  }
  return diceTotal;
}
```

Further explanation:

Attributes can be added to any element and can be named anything and given any string value.  Excessive use can get messy and it is generally better practice to store information in variables within your javascript but this was a relatively simple example.

The attribute diceValue is used to hold the numerical value of your die.  After the above three lines the markup for diceSideOne will look like this:
`<li class="dice dice-side-one" dicevalue="1"></li>`.

The `dicevalue="1"` part of that element is what we will be looking up later when finding the total value of all dice added.

The `getSumDiceValue` function first grabs all elements with the class `dice` and saves them for later use in the variable `dice` (this is an array of your `.dice` elements).

To find the sum of all dice values from this point we need to look at every element in that array of dice and access their `dicevalue` attribute.

A for loop is used to look at every element in the `dice` array, `dice[i].getAttribute('diceValue')` will give us the value tied to the `dicevalue` attribute ("1", "2", etc).  That is wrapped in `Number()` to convert it from a string to a number we can use.

The `diceTotal` variable starts at 0 and each time through the loop we add the `dicevalue` number to it.  Once the loop is finished the final line `return diceTotal;` makes our function return the sum of all dicevalues.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I've just recently started JavaScript and I'm trying to get my head around it =).

Would this increase/decrease if i added/removed a die "on the go" so to speak?

Comment: To store custom data, better use `data-*` attributes.

Comment: I added some clarifaction, sorry if I was a little verbose I just didn't know how much detail you wanted.  This will return the correct value as you add and remove dice as long as the dice element is removed entirely.

Comment: Really good information, if you don't mind, one more thing. How would I go about "plugging" the code in to here:
`var totalDiceSumm = document.createElement("p");
totalDiceSumm.className = "dice-summ";
totalDiceSumm.innerHTML = "hello there";
diceToolbarCounterWrapper.appendChild(totalDiceSumm); `

instead of "hello there" the summ would be.

Comment: You would write `totalDiceSumm.innerHTML = getSumDiceValue();`.  Since that function returns a number, that number will be displayed inside.  You could also append text to that number like this `= 'Dice Total: ' + getSumDiceValue();`

Comment: Keep in mind that you will need to refresh the contents of `totalDiceSumm` every time you add or remove a die in order to keep it accurate.  If  you have a function to remove/add then you could add `document.getElementsByClassName('dice-summ')[0].innerHTML = getSumDiceValue();` to the end of those functions to keep it updated.

Comment: It's working! Thank you so much for your patience and for all of your help! I am super grateful! =)

Comment: Great to hear!  Good luck and have fun with your studies!

Answer (score 0):

1) Select all elements with class dice

2) Loop over the elements and for each check the other class

3) Based off the class name add that number (if dice-side-two then 2)

Comment: Hello thanks for your quick reply! I'm a total noob at this. Could you explain a little bit more indepth or perhaps add a code example? =)